# How do I provide custom accessibility text for ios local notification content - UNNotificationContent

Tags: ios, swift, voiceover, uiaccessibility, unusernotificationcenter

I'm trying to provide custom text for voiceover user instead of reading the body text.

E.g., the current body text is say *"Apple stock $203.03 ↑"* it reads as *"Apple stock two hundred three dollars and three cents up arrow"* but I wanted to read as *"Apple stock two hundred three dollars and three cents in green"*

The following code did not work:

```
let content = UNMutableNotificationContent()
content.body = "Apple stock $203.03 ↑"
content.accessibilityLabel = "Apple stock two hundred three dollars and three cents in green"
content.accessibilityHint = "I am an Hint"
```

Even the hint is not spoken.

Let me know if it is possible to achieve this?

Is there anyway to achieve this in default notification ( Notification Content Extension works only after user expand the notification)

Comment: Have you found out any solution that could remove my bug report about your question since I wrote my answer, please? 

Comment: @XLE_22 No. Created Radar/Feedback ticket no update. And followed up with Accessibility evangelist, they said it is in their system/backlog, that is all :-(

Answer (score 2):

> Let me know if it is possible to achieve this?

Actually, **you can't**. 
I wrote a **D**eveloper **T**echnical **S**upport **I**ncident *(no 731462771)* whose Apple's answer definitely admits that it's a bug they can't provide a workaround.

I submitted a bug report entitled **VoiceOver: can't change change accessibilityLabel for UNMutableNotificationContent** with the reference **FB7640821** in order to fix this problem as soon as possible *(the next iOS version ?* *)*.

Now, you know why you can't **provide custom accessibility text for iOS local notification content**... until it's fixed by Apple itself.

Answer (score 1):

Base on this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130573/how-can-i-set-an-accessibility-trait-for-the-placeholder-text-in-uitextfield):

Try to set the `accessibilityValue` like:

`content.accessibilityValue = "Apple stock two hundred three dollars and three cents in green"`

If it does not work, try setting the `accessibilityLabel` to the value you want and subclassing the `UNMutableNotificationContent` to override the `accessibilityValue` property.

```
class CustomUNMutableNotificationContent: UNMutableNotificationContent {
    override public var accessibilityValue: String? {
        get { return self.accessibilityLabel }
        set { super.accessibilityValue = newValue }
    }
}
```

Comment: I just saw the code you printed, in the subclass when overriding the `accessibilityValue` you're returning the `accessibilityValue` again. Can you replace it with `accessibilityLabel` and see if it works?

Comment: Ok... instead, if you override the `accessibilityValue` and returns the text "Apple stock two hundred three dollars and three cents in green" instead of the `accessibilityLabel`, does it says it correctly?