# Is there any way to disable accessibility voice-over of placeholder text in UITextField?

Tags: ios, uikit, accessibility, voiceover

I am using `UITextField` for search text bar in my app.
I always want to set `accessibiliyLabel` to text field as "Search for file". 
I also want to set placeholder to "Search for file".

But when i start iOS voice-over and if input text in " "(empty) then `Search for file` is spoken twice (i.e one form `accessibilityLabel` and another form placeholder). 
If some input text in present in text field that only `accessibilityLabel` is spoken along with input text.

**Is there any way to disable placeholder text accessibility?**

Comment: If you have a proper label, it is not clear to me why you would also want to display the same text as a placeholder. That is like a belt-and-braces approach, unless the label is not visible.

Comment: Hi Christopher, thanks for going through my question.
If some user are blind  then they should get voice over feedback with help of  `UITextField.accessibilityLabel` (i.e Placeholder is not visible to him).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found this answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10130573/how-can-i-set-an-accessibility-trait-for-the-placeholder-text-in-uitextfield):

```
class MyTextField: UITextField {
    override public var accessibilityValue: String? {
        get { return self.text }
        set { super.accessibilityValue = newValue }
    }
}
```

You're going to prevent your `UITextField` from using your `placeholder`
 as the `accessibilityValue` by always returning the `text` attribute instead. Have in mind that using something like `textField.accessibilityValue = text` won't work.

Comment: Thanks Andre for reply!. This works fine.
Here is my conclusion - 
In `UITextField`, If `text is empty or `nil`, then placeholder text will be returned as `accessibilityValue` otherwise `text` will be returned.
To override `UITextField.accessibilityValue` default behavior to use this.